# Load video on appear Swift using wkwebview

Tags: swift, xcode, video, wkwebview

I figured out how to display normal YouTube videos and shorts along with any video on the internet in my app. I would like these videos to auto play when they appear and I can't figure out how.

I tried the following code below, it loads the video when it appears but the video never plays. I have 2 different structs to display YouTube videos and plain only online videos. I've only tried to modify the WebVideoView struct to auto play the video. But I'm assuming whatever I have to do for one can also be done for the other.

```
import SwiftUI
import WebKit

struct YouTubeView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let link: String
    let short: Bool
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        return WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    }
    
    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        var embedHTML = ""
        
        if short {
            let realLink = link.dropFirst(7)
            
            embedHTML = """
            <body style="background-color:\(colorScheme == .dark ? "black" : "white"); display: flex; justify-content: center; align-items: center;">
                <iframe
                width="500"
                height="950"
                src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/\(realLink)?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </body>
            """
        } else {
            embedHTML = """
            <body style="background-color:\(colorScheme == .dark ? "black" : "white");">
                <iframe
                width=450"
                height="280"
                src="https://www.youtube.com/embed/\(link)?autoplay=1" frameborder="0" allowfullscreen></iframe>
            </body>
            """
        }
        
        uiView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        uiView.loadHTMLString(embedHTML, baseURL: nil)
    }
}

struct WebVideoView: UIViewRepresentable {
    let link: String
    @Environment(\.colorScheme) var colorScheme

    func makeUIView(context: Context) -> WKWebView {
        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        return WKWebView(frame: .zero, configuration: webConfiguration)
    }

    func updateUIView(_ uiView: WKWebView, context: Context) {
        let html = """
        <body style="background-color:\(colorScheme == .dark ? "black" : "white");display: flex; justify-content: center;">
            <video
            src="\(link)"
            width="950" height="536"
            controls
            playsinline="true"
            autoplay>
        </body>
        """

        let script = """
        var video = document.querySelector('video');
        video.addEventListener('loadedmetadata', function() {
            video.play();
        });
        """

        let userScript = WKUserScript(source: script, injectionTime: .atDocumentEnd, forMainFrameOnly: false)
        let userContentController = WKUserContentController()
        userContentController.addUserScript(userScript)

        let webConfiguration = WKWebViewConfiguration()
        webConfiguration.userContentController = userContentController
        webConfiguration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true

        uiView.scrollView.isScrollEnabled = false
        uiView.loadHTMLString(html, baseURL: nil)
        uiView.configuration.allowsInlineMediaPlayback = true
        uiView.configuration.userContentController = userContentController
    }
}
```